# Cannot write to a Snowflake table but with no errors returned

Tags: python, pandas, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The code runs successfully with no errors returned, but only old records displayed:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from snowflake.sqlalchemy import URL
from config import config

engine = create_engine(URL(account=config.account, 
          user=config.username, 
          password=config.password, 
          warehouse=config.warehouse, 
          database=config.database, 
          schema=config.schema,))
    
conn = engine.connect()
    
df = pd.DataFrame([('AAA', '1234'), ('BBB', '5678')], columns=['name', 'pswd'])
df.to_sql('demo_db.public.test_f1', con=engine, index=False, if_exists='append', index_label=None)
        
df = pd.read_sql_query('select * from demo_db.public.test_f1', conn)
print(df.head(5))
    
conn.close()
engine.dispose()
```

Please help!

Comment: Can you share what the Snowflake query history shows for these statements?

Comment: I did not get your point here. I used print(df.head(5)) to show the first 5 rows in the table, also I went to snowflake and preview the data of the table, no new records got added at all.

Comment: @FrankDuan Maybe the name was automatically quoted and the table is is accessible as: `SELECT * FROM demo_db.public."demo_db.public.test_f1"`;

Comment: shot in the dark here.. do you need to supply snowflake role when making engine? i know the concept of role throws people off a lot in snowflake.

Comment: @Lukasz Szozda
You are right! I changed it to:
        df.to_sql('test_f1', con=engine, index=False, if_exists='append', index_label=None)               
And it works!  Many thanks!

Comment: Can you give a wrong table name and see if it errors out with a message that Object dose not exist. Also check if the Auto Commit is ON or Off in your Snowflake environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the 3 part name was treated as single identifier and data was inserted into table called `"demo_db.public.test_f1"`:

```
SELECT * FROM demo_db.public."demo_db.public.test_f1";
```

The [name](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) could be provided as table name only and database/schema are inferred from connection:

```
df.to_sql('test_f1', con=engine, index=False, if_exists='append', index_label=None)
```